# Set Alpha/Opacity of Layout

Tags: java, android, user-interface

Is it possible to set and get the Alpha/Opacity of a Layout and all it's child views? I'm not talking about the background. Say a collection of Video Controls like Play, Pause and Progressbar in a Relative Layout.

I can use animation to fade in and out but wanted to know if there was a direct method I could use.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can set the alpha on the layout and it's children (or any other view for that matter) using AlphaAnimation with 0 duration and setFillAfter option.

Example:

```
AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0.5F, 0.5F);
alpha.setDuration(0); // Make animation instant
alpha.setFillAfter(true); // Tell it to persist after the animation ends
// And then on your layout
yourLayout.startAnimation(alpha);
```

You can use one animation for multiple components to save memory. And do reset() to use again, or clearAnimation() to drop alpha.

Though it looks crude and hacked it's actually a good way to set alpha on set ov views that doesn't take much memory or processor time.

Not sure about getting current alpha value though.

Comment: Thanks. I was using animation but I was setting the object visibility to gone once the animation had completed instead of using the setFillAfter method.

Comment: It seems to break the animations (if run during the animation). Any fix for this?

Comment: As a workaround, I used a semi-transparent image set as background of a `View`.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a method that works across all versions ([thanks to @AlexOrlov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4814651/1306903)):

```java
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static void setAlpha(View view, float alpha)
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
    {
        final AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(alpha, alpha);
        animation.setDuration(0);
        animation.setFillAfter(true);
        view.startAnimation(animation);
    }
    else view.setAlpha(alpha);
}
```

Clearly, for API less than 11 if you can you should create a custom view that calls `Canvas.saveLayerAlpha()` before drawing its children ([thanks to @RomainGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4815101/1306903)).

Comment: Use: ViewCompat.setAlpha(View, float).

Answer (score 6):

Alex's solution works but another way is to create a custom view that calls Canvas.saveLayerAlpha() before drawing its children. Note that in Android 3.0 there is a new View.setAlpha() API :)

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to the setAlpha method. Something I'm more use to from other languages.

Answer (score 3):

Now you can use [`ViewCompat.setAlpha(View, float)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#setAlpha(android.view.View%2C%20float)) for this action.

Comment: Quote from doc: "*Prior to API 11 this will have no effect.*"

Comment: there is No such method. I have set minimum api set to 11.But it has ViewCompat.getAlpha(anyView) method

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my answer but if you want the alpha you can use the ViewCompat Class

ViewCompat.setAlpha(View view, float alpha)

ViewCompat is in the appcompat v4