# Animation engine does not animate a view

Tags: android

I have the following animation

```
ValueAnimator colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(contentBg, "backgroundColor", /*transparent*/0x0, /*dark*/0xcc000000);
        colorAnim.setDuration(3000);
        colorAnim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
        colorAnim.start();
```

so what I want is to animate a contentBg from transparent to almost opaque dark. However, what I gets is just a transparent view, and after 3 seconds it gets instantly dark (end value of animation).
What should I do to make it work properly? 
I am using nineoldandroids lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually solved it myself by narrowing down my question to animating just alpha.
[How to set View alpha in lower Api than 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578010/how-to-set-view-alpha-in-lower-api-than-11)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to animate alpha only?

```
ValueAnimator colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(contentBg, View.ALPHA, 0, 0.8);
colorAnim.setDuration(3000);
colorAnim.start();
```

**EDIT:** from [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids/issues/28)  it seems there is a problem with ArgbEvaluator evaluating alpha values. You can try the patched version provided in https://github.com/EaseTheWorld/PaintAnimator/blob/master/src/dev/easetheworld/animator/ArgbEvaluator2.java

Comment: This works for API11, since alpha property was introdoced only in api11, isn't it?

Comment: The first one yes, but with NineOldandroids you should be able to just change View.ALPHA with "alpha"... But for your case using ArgbEvaluator2 should be a better choice