# Make button be less visible but not gone

Tags: android, button, viewgroup

A couple of weeks ago I think I read something about makeing a Button or any other View group a bit faded or less visible to show that it is not in use, but can be used if the user does something. Now I can not find it anywhere, and I really want to use it.

Does anyone know what it is and if it is useable in android 2.1?

Comment: Use the same image but decrease its opacity.

Comment: M Mohsin Naeem it kind of worked but not what I was looking for.

Comment: but you accept same answer which states my comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use below method , if Button is not enable and you want to show user that it is not in use.

```
mButton.setEnabled(false); // if it is not enable and you want to show user that it is not in use.
```

and

```
mButton.setEnabled(true); // to make it enabled/ in use
```

Comment: ok, this is the way Android docs suggest to achieve what you want. All the best

Answer (score 1):

//give 0 for full transparent  255 for completely opaque.

```
Mybutt.getBackground().setAlpha(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
mButton.getBackground().setAlpha(127); // semi transparent
```

Comment: The button is still clickable

Comment: @Magakahn then implement your own CustomButton and Override the setEnabled(boolean) method to change its opacity =)

Comment: I am pretty sure it was a state not a replacement

Comment: @Magakahn of course you can use a [StateList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) too

Comment: But it was a already defined state. I think I have found it now and it is called disabeled. http://developer.android.com/design/style/touch-feedback.html

Comment: @Magakahn this state is used when the button's state is disabled, so why don't you just call mButton.setEnabled(false) ?

Comment: I found it out now. One of (in my case edittext) where focused and could still be selected after disabeling it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [AlphaAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AlphaAnimation.html) on any view / viewgroup and its children.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4814651/1117415).

Comment: I think it was a disabeled state or something, I am pretty sure it was not that.

Comment: You say in your OP: "but can be used if the user does something". So you don't want it to be disabled.

Comment: For exapmple take a registration screen where you can disable some of the buttons by a checkbox.