# Error with setAlpha

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

hi guys i need your help because of this error:

here is the logcat:

```
07-30 16:12:33.823: E/AndroidRuntime(21283): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.LinearLayout.setAlpha
07-30 16:12:33.823: E/AndroidRuntime(21283):    at it.bisemanuDEV.piano.livello1$1.onClick(livello1.java:393)
07-30 16:12:33.823: E/AndroidRuntime(21283):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-30 16:12:33.823: E/AndroidRuntime(21283):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8819)
07-30 16:12:33.823: E/AndroidRuntime(21283):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:603)
07-30 16:12:33.823: E/AndroidRuntime(21283):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-30 16:12:33.823: E/AndroidRuntime(21283):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-30 16:12:33.823: E/AndroidRuntime(21283):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-30 16:12:33.823: E/AndroidRuntime(21283):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 16:12:33.823: E/AndroidRuntime(21283):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-30 16:12:33.823: E/AndroidRuntime(21283):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-30 16:12:33.823: E/AndroidRuntime(21283):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-30 16:12:33.823: E/AndroidRuntime(21283):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I think this could help you :) (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.LinearLayout.setAlpha.. aka in the linear layout element you cannot use setAlpha)


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813995/set-alpha-opacity-of-layout

Comment: I refer you http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html. Which gives you some information about why this error occurs.

Comment: setAlpha method is only available since API number 11. Get the latest ADT and run the lint tool. It has many rules to detect this kind of error.

Answer (score 5):

`setAlpha()` was introduced in API11.  You could be getting this error because you are supporting too low of an API for this method.  Since it doesn't exist at an API < 11 the compiler will throw a `NoSuchMethodError` exception.  You could also accidentally be overloading the method by not passing through a float.  If the API level is the problem, you might want to try the link that sataniccrow provided: [Set Alpha/Opacity of Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813995/set-alpha-opacity-of-layout)