# how to change the alpha value of imageview

Tags: android, image, alpha

In my app I want to change the ImageView like the following.
I want only to change the image on the body.

[image]

I have followed the following link to change the alpha values by using the code like that

```
imageView.setAlpha(255);
```

But it is not working.

[How to Set Opacity (Alpha) for View in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838757/how-to-set-opacity-alpha-for-view-in-android).
   Please anybody suggest me how to do that.

Comment: So post your code what you're doing

Comment: pass alpha value between 0 to 1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4814651/

Answer (score 4):

Or, without using animation you can just use [`setAlpha(float alpha)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setAlpha%28int%29) on your `ImageView`.

Comment: setalpha is available for api 11+!

Comment: whenever I try to put alpha by this method I cant see any changes! iv.setAlpha(50f) or iv.setImageAlpha(50) nothing happens ? WHY

Comment: As written in android developer doc : . This is a value from 0 to 1, where 0 means the view is completely transparent and 1 means the view is completely opaque.
You should try with setAlpha(0.2f)

Answer (score 4):

It might be because [setAlpha(float Alpha)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setAlpha%28int%29) has been deprecated as of API level 16 by [setImageAlpha(float Alpha)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageAlpha%28int%29)

Comment: `setAlpha(float)` isn't deprecated, only `setAlpha(int)`

Answer (score 1):

Opacity ranges between 0 to 1, and you have given the value as 255,
**imageView.setAlpha(255)**.

So give the value between 0 to 1, such as when

you want the opacity of 50%, give 0.5.
imageView.setAlpha(0.5f)

Also you can do it in XML file as follows:
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewIcon"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:alpha=".5"