# Alternative to setAlpha in api level 8

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-2.2-froyo

I am working on an app, which can run on `Froyo` as well as `JellyBean`. I have a class that extends PageTransformer as below:

```
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.PageTransformer;
import android.view.View;

public class ZoomOutPageTransformer implements PageTransformer {
    private static float MIN_SCALE = 0.85f;
    private static float MIN_ALPHA = 0.5f;

    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
        int pageHeight = view.getHeight();

        if (position < -1) { 
            view.setAlpha(0);

        } else if (position <= 1) { 
            float scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_SCALE, 1 - Math.abs(position));
            float vertMargin = pageHeight * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
            float horzMargin = pageWidth * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
            if (position < 0) {
                view.setTranslationX(horzMargin - vertMargin / 2);
            } else {
                view.setTranslationX(-horzMargin + vertMargin / 2);
            }


            view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
            view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);


            view.setAlpha(MIN_ALPHA +
                    (scaleFactor - MIN_SCALE) /
                    (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - MIN_ALPHA));

        } else { 
            view.setAlpha(0);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, the methods written in this class were added in `API level 11` and i have minimum sdk version of `API level 8`. The following are those methods that were added in API level 11:

1. `setAlpha()`
2. `setTranslationX()`
3. `setScaleX()`
4. `setScaleY()`

What can be the solution for this problem ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4814651/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use the [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) library, which backports the animations to all versions of Android. The [Usage section](http://nineoldandroids.com/#usage) has examples of how you'd use the library.

Comment: Yes. When searched for the solution, i found, most of them were recommended for this NineOldAndroids. But I don't understand how to implement this. Can you guide me how to implement for the above class i've written.

Comment: @shree202 - take a look at the [ViewHelper](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids/blob/master/library/src/com/nineoldandroids/view/ViewHelper.java) class - just use ViewHelper.setAlpha(view, alpha) rather than view.setAlpha(alpha), etc.

Answer (score 51):

**setAlphaAnimation … API LEVEL 1**

Here is some relevant code I copied from the answer at [Set Alpha/Opacity of Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813995/set-alpha-opacity-of-layout/4814651#4814651) —

> ```
> AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0.7F, 0.7F);
> alpha.setDuration(0); // Make animation instant
> alpha.setFillAfter(true); // Tell it to persist after the animation
> ends view.startAnimation(alpha);
> ```

---

**setAlpha INT -> From API LEVEL 1 -> deprecated in 16**

```
Drawable background = localLinLayout.getBackground();
background.setAlpha(180); //255 is max (visible)
```

---

**`setAlpha` FLOAT -> API Level 11+ ->**

---

**`setImageAlpha` -> API LEVEL 16+** (use just for ImageViews)

Comment: what about others like setScaleX() setScaleY() ?

Comment: as define in question

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is *cough* lazy and wants the ZoomOutPageTransformer compatible back to API 8. Uses nineoldandroids and the ViewHelper class.

```
package com.weddingwire.vendorsearch.Animation;

import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;

import com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper;

public class ZoomOutPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
    private static float MIN_SCALE = 0.85f;
    private static float MIN_ALPHA = 0.5f;

    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
        int pageHeight = view.getHeight();

        if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            ViewHelper.setAlpha(view, 0);

        } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
            // Modify the default slide transition to shrink the page as well
            float scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_SCALE, 1 - Math.abs(position));
            float vertMargin = pageHeight * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
            float horzMargin = pageWidth * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
            if (position < 0) {
                ViewHelper.setTranslationX(view, (horzMargin - vertMargin / 2));
            } else {
                ViewHelper.setTranslationX(view, -horzMargin + vertMargin / 2);
            }

            // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
            ViewHelper.setScaleX(view, scaleFactor);
            ViewHelper.setScaleY(view, scaleFactor);

            // Fade the page relative to its size.
            ViewHelper.setAlpha(view, MIN_ALPHA +
                    (scaleFactor - MIN_SCALE) /
                            (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - MIN_ALPHA));

        } else { // (1,+Infinity]
            // This page is way off-screen to the right.
            ViewHelper.setAlpha(view, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Now this one would provide a nice help to some one.

Answer (score 2):

Also, If you want use `PageTransformer` even in 2.2. You must change some validation that are made in the `ViewPager` class. Check out this [example](https://github.com/astinx/PageTransformerSupport)

Answer (score 2):

To be both forward and backward compatible I use following implementation for my views:

```
private void fadeOut(final View view) {
    int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f);
        alpha.setDuration(mAnimationDuration);
        alpha.setFillAfter(true);
        view.startAnimation(alpha);
    } else {
        view.animate()
        .alpha(0f)
        .setDuration(mAnimationDuration)
        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
}

private void fadeIn(View view) {
    int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0f, 1f);
        alpha.setDuration(mAnimationDuration);
        alpha.setFillAfter(true);
        view.startAnimation(alpha);
    } else {
        view.setAlpha(0f);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        view.animate()
        .alpha(1f)
        .setDuration(mAnimationDuration)
        .setListener(null);
    }
}
```