# How to change the Alpha of an ImageView in android

Tags: android, imageview

I have five `ImageViews` declared in the `layout` file. All of them have src attribute set to some image.

I want to give some effect something like changing the alpha value when you click on an image to the images.

Here is my code

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewNews"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/news" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewBookmark"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/bookmark" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16417259/1723525

Comment: You might want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755551/alternative-to-setalpha-in-api-level-8

Comment: May this help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931071/android-and-setting-alpha-for-image-view-alpha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XML  use

```
android:alpha="" alpha between 0 to 1
```

In code use

```
imageView.setAlpha(int);
```

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931071/android-and-setting-alpha-for-image-view-alpha/16417259#16417259)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931071/android-and-setting-alpha-for-image-view-alpha

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is to use `ViewCompat.setAlpha`

```
  ViewCompat.setAlpha(imageViewInstace, alpha);
```

where `alpha` is a float between 0 and 1