# Button not showing color in android?

Tags: android, xml

This is the XML for the button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:color="#048b9dc3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/login"
     />
```

The button is the default gray color in the app instead of semi transparent blue color I've set above. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set background instead of color. Add this block :

```
android:background="YOUR_COLOR_CODE_HERE"
```

Also your color code is not proper. You can use photoshop for finding color code which you want.

Comment: So you can set alpha with `android:alpha="0.4"`

Comment: Nope, supported on API level 11 and above only.

Comment: Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813995/set-alpha-opacity-of-layout)

Answer (score 0):

You can either set it in XML file:-

Or set it in your java program:-

button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

Or you can just write the 4-byte hex code (not 3-byte) 0xFF000000

http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/setting-buttons-colors/