# Custom RatingBar - setting alpha on a particular state

Tags: android

For custom rating bar, is there a way to set the alpha on the images. Directly doing setAlpha on the rating bar doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: You could try using an AlphaAnimation like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813995/set-alpha-opacity-of-layout

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use setAlpha take care to check SDK, in case > 15 you need to use setImageAlpha() instead setAlpha()

```
        if (SDK_INT > 15) {
            ratingBar.setImageAlpha(255);
        } else {
            ratingBar.setAlpha(255);
        }
```

Comment: ratingBar.setImageAlpha doesn't seem to be an option as it doesn't inherit any of the ImageView properties.